# display images in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I use UICollectionview, and custom cell.

So I created a NSArray with names of images and when I try to put in my custom cell but nothing appears, I do not understand why it is happening.

in viewDidLoad

```
 [super viewDidLoad];



albums = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"noImage.png",@"noImage.png",@"noImage.png",@"noImage.png",@"noImage.png",@"noImage.png",@"noImage.png",@"noImage.png", nil];


[self.collectionView registerClass:[CVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CVCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(150, 150)];

//[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

here my cellForItemAtIndexPath method that displays my cell

```
-(CVCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

CVCell *cell = (CVCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnail.png"]];

cell.picture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
```

}

and I feel that this action does not work or when I hurt things "
***cell.picture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];cell.picture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];***"

thx

Comment: What you have should work (although there's no need to register the class, only the nib is fine). Did you make your controller the delegate and data source for the collection view? Did you hook up the outlet, collectionView, in IB? Are you seeing your background image?

Comment: Does the thumbnail.png show up in the backgroundView?

Comment: I see my cell that appears but I am unable to view the images in a Array ablums